# three.js lookAt function does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to align one child object (the cylinder) to another object (cube2). I used the lookAt Function, but the alignment is not correct. Where is my mistake?

I have the following code:

```
    //cube 1
    var cube=new THREE.BoxGeometry(2,2,2);
    var material=new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial ({ color: 0xffffff });
    mesh1=new THREE.Mesh(cube,material);
    mesh1.position.set(-2,2,0);
    scene.add(mesh1);

    //cube 2
    var cube2=new THREE.BoxGeometry(2,2,2);
    var material=new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial ({ color:0x000000 });
    mesh2=new THREE.Mesh(cube2,material);
    mesh2.position.x=6;
    mesh2.position.y=2;
    scene.add(mesh2);   

    //cylinder
    var cylinder=new THREE.CylinderGeometry(1,1,5,30);
    var material=new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color:0xff3399 });
    mesh3=new THREE.Mesh(cylinder,material);
    mesh3.position.x=4.5;


    mesh3.lookAt(mesh2.position);
    mesh1.add(mesh3);
```

The left cube is cube1 and the right cube is cube2. The cylinder is the child element of cube1 and should lookAt cube2. So if I move cube 1 (in y-Position) , the cylinder should rotate and always look at cube2.

[Here is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUjDn.png)

Comment: LookAt totate mesh towards vector in a space, where is added.

Comment: Do you have a solution for my problem?

Comment: mesh3.lookAt(mesh2.position.subVectors ( mesh2.position, mesh1.position )) ??

Answer (score 0):

`LookAt` rotate mesh towards `vector` in a space, where is added.

```
   mesh2.position` is [6,2,0]
   mesh1 position` is [-2,2,0]
```

if you set mesh3.lookAt(mesh2.position) inside mesh1 it will "looks" on vector `[6-2,2+2,0] = [4,4,0]`;

If you want to look on correct position you must calculate this to your target vector.

see https://threejs.org/docs/api/math/Vector3.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that also does not work how I have imagined. I updated my question with a picture, maybe that helps to understand what I want to realize.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, you don't need to use hierachy of objects in this case.

It's better to set position of the cylinder to the first object and then to call .lookAt() with the position of the second object.

So, let's imagine you have an array of objects

```
var cubes = [];
```

and links between them

```
var links = [];
```

then you create links, like so:

```
function linkObj(startObj, endObj) {
    var linkGeom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.12, 0.25, 1, 16);
    linkGeom.translate(0, 0.5, 0);
    linkGeom.rotateX(Math.PI / 2);
    var link = new THREE.Mesh(linkGeom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: "yellow"
    }));
    link.userData.position = startObj;
    link.userData.lookAt = endObj;
    scene.add(link);
    links.push(link);
  }
```

and link objects:

```
linkObj(0, 1);  // where 0 and 1 are indices of objects in the array
```

in the end you'll add calculation of position and point of lookAt in your animation loop:

```
  links.forEach(function(link){
    link.position.copy(cubes[link.userData.position].position);
    link.lookAt(cubes[link.userData.lookAt].position);
    link.scale.z = cubes[link.userData.position].position.distanceTo(cubes[link.userData.lookAt].position);
  });
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/tfethwfe/) example

PS Cubes in the example are draggable