# Align BoxGeometry between two 3D Points

Tags: javascript, three.js

I make a game where you can add objects to a world without using a grid. Now I want to make a footpath. When you click on "Create footpath", then you can add a point to on the world at the raycaster position. After you add a first point you can add a second point to the world. When these 2 objects where placed. A line/footpath is visible from the first point to the second one.

I can do this really simple with `THREE.Line`. See the code:

```
var lineGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
lineGeometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(x1,0,z1), new THREE.Vector3(x2,0,z2) );
lineGeometry.computeLineDistances();
var lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xFF0000 } );
var line = new THREE.Line( lineGeometry, lineMaterial );
scene.add(line);
```

But I can't add a texture on a simple line. Now I want to do something the same with a Mesh. I have the position of the first point and the raycaster position of the second point. I also have the lenght between the two objects for the lenght of the footpath. But I don't know how I can get the rotation what is needed.

*Note. I saw something about `LookAt`, is this maybe a good idea, how can I use this with a mesh?*

Can anyone help me to get the correct rotation for the footpath object?

I use this code for the foodpath mesh:

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.load('images/floor.jpg', function ( texture ) {
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10, 0, 2);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture, overdraw: 0.5 });
    var footpath = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    footpath.position.copy(point2);
    var direction = // What can I do here?
    footpath.rotation.y = direction;
    scene.add(footpath);
});
```

I want to get the correct rotation for `direction`.

**[UPDATE]**
The code of WestLangley helps a lot. But it works not in all directions. I used this code for the lenght:

```
var lenght = footpaths[i].position.z - point2.position.z;
```

What can I do that the lenght works in all directions?

[image]

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41678777/4045502) answer and have a look at its jsfiddle example. It's about `.lookAt()` and connectors between points.

Comment: If the distance is dynamic, then it's better to set the `length` to 1 (`var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( width, height, 1 );`) and then to scale it like `footpah.scale.z = point1.distanceTo(point2)`. It's in the related answer from my previous comment. And WestLangley is right - to change a question after it's been answered is not a good manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to align a box between two 3D points. You can do that like so:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( width, height, length ); // align length with z-axis

geometry.translate( 0, 0, length / 2 ); // so one end is at the origin

...

var footpath = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

footpath.position.copy( point1 );

footpath.lookAt( point2 );
```

three.js r.84

Comment: Thanks for you help. I update my question. Do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: Do not change the question after is has been answered. `length = point1.distanceTo( point2 );`